# Why am I not getting any response from socket.io connection event

Tags: javascript, express, server, socket.io

I have just started with socket.io and to practice I wanted to create a server whose output tells me 'A user connected' every time a connection with the client is established. I thought that a connection is established just by starting the server and going to `localhost:5000`. After that I would see the output message from the connection in my console.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('I am alive')
})

PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 

const server = app.listen( PORT, 
    () =>{ console.log(`Listening to http://localhost:${PORT}`)})

const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');})
```

For this process, I type `node server.js`, wait until the message `Listening to http://localhost:5000` appears and then I go to the page. But when I navigate to the page I see no console message.
Is a html file necessary for the message to appear? Or am I not seeing a important step? I have seen some tutorials but all of them use a html file, and I wanted to avoid that step.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server by writing this code

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
     console.log('A user connected');
 })
```

you are listening to the connection and somebody, somewhere has to connect to the socket of this server on same url as your server is for example like this

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect', function () {
     socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
        setResponse(data);
     });
     socket.emit("FromAPI")
 }
```

When you make socket connection anywhere either in html or any other code the console.log() will print data on server

Comment: Did you define socketIOClient as `const socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client')`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is the server end you need to setup client as well.

Client End:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:<PORT>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```